# Laravel Fluent/Eloquent - check for related rows

Tags: php, laravel, relationship, eloquent, fluent

I currently have a simple situation which I'm trying to find a good solution for - in my app, one Post has zero-to-many comments. I'm trying to work out how to query with either Fluent or Eloquent to find only the posts which have comments attached.

At the moment, the best I've been able to come up with is

```
Post::with('comments')->whereNotNull('comment.id')->get();
```

which fails because just doing `with('comments')` doesn't actually run a join on that table.

I've tried Googling and looking at some other SO posts, but haven't been able to find anything useful - is there some simple solution I'm completely missing out on?

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on Anams response, you can do any of the following

```
Post::has('comments')->get();
Post::has('comments', '>', 0)->get();
Post::has('comments', '>=', 1)->get();
```

For more information on querying relations, check out the laravel documentation http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#querying-relations.

Comment: Cheers, much appreciated - I knew there was some way of doing it because I'd read it somewhere but couldn't remember what it was to save my life ^_^

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

`Post::has('comments')->get();`

Comment: Thanks - I've marked ollie's as the correct answer as it has a little more info so it's useful if anyone else finds this thread, but I've upvoted you :)